# How to fix badly opening Chrome window in Elementary OS

Tags: chrome, elementary-os, window

When opening Chrome in Elementary OS (fresh install) I see the animation of the window opening to a side of the screen (where I can't access). I don't know why this happens and neither how to get access to the window, therefore chrome is useless right now.

Can I fix this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

There used to be an command line option to chrome you could try,
but sadly this is not something you can rely on:

```
chromium-browser --window-position=10,10
```

So one possible tactic is to install `xdotool` and use it to list all window ids matching the name `chromium` (which is what the browser goes under),
and then use xdotool to get their size:

```
xdotool search chromium|xargs -i xdotool getwindowgeometry {}
```

Choose the largest, eg:

```
Window 52428801
  Position: 6,6 (screen: 0)
  Geometry: 1627x985
```

and move that window with

```
xdotool windowmove 52428801 0 0
```

Move the window again with the mouse, close it, and the restart 
chrome and see if it remembers where it was placed last time.